# convert array to struct pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I'm quite new to pyspark and I have a dataframe that currently looks like below.

```
| col1                            | col2              |
+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| [(a, 0)], [(b,0)].....[(z,1)]   | [0, 0, ... 1]     |
| [(b, 0)], [(b,1)].....[(z,0)]   | [0, 1, ... 0]     |
| [(a, 0)], [(c, 1)].....[(z,0)]  | [0, 1, ... 0]     |
```

I extracted values from `col1.QueryNum` into col2 and when I print the schema, it's an array containing the list of number from `col1.QueryNum`.

Ultimately my goal is to convert the list values in `col2` into struct format inside pyspark(refer to desired schema).

**Current Schema**

```
 |-- col1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- types: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- QueryNum: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

**Desired Schema**

```
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- val1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val2: integer (nullable = true)
                 .
                 .
                 .
 |    |    |-- val80: integer (nullable = true)
```

I tried using `from_json` and it's not really working.

Comment: And what is `val1` and `val2`? how many elements do you have in `col1`? It's not clear in your example

Comment: I have updated my question, hope it's clearer now

Comment: sorry I can't understand why you want to have array of structs instead of simple array of values in `col2`. what if you have 3 elements in the `col1` would you add `val3` in struct of `col2` then?

Comment: the reason is I need to assign a name for each of the val1, val2 ... val80, this is for convenience in the following data processing step. The number of elements are fixed, there are 80 elements in total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the you have fixed array size you can create struct using list-comprehension:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "col2",
    F.array(
        F.struct(*[
            F.col("col1")[i]["QueryNum"].alias(f"val{i+1}") for i in range(2)
        ])
    )
)

df1.show()
#+----------------+--------+
#|col1            |col2    |
#+----------------+--------+
#|[[0, a], [0, b]]|[[0, 0]]|
#|[[0, b], [1, b]]|[[0, 1]]|
#|[[0, a], [1, c]]|[[0, 1]]|
#+----------------+--------+

df1.printSchema()
#root
#|-- col1: array (nullable = true)
#|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#|    |    |-- QueryNum: long (nullable = true)
#|    |    |-- types: string (nullable = true)
#|-- col2: array (nullable = false)
#|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#|    |    |-- val1: long (nullable = true)
#|    |    |-- val2: long (nullable = true)
```

Note however that there is no need to use array in this case as you'll always have one struct in that array. Just use simple struct:

```
df1 = df.withColumn(
    "col2",
    F.struct(*[
        F.col("col1")[i]["QueryNum"].alias(f"val{i+1}") for i in range(2)
    ])
)
```

Or if you prefer a map type:

```
df1 = df.withColumn(
    "col2",
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.expr("transform(col1, (x,i) -> struct('val' || (i+1) as name, x.QueryNum as value))")
    )
)
```

Comment: thanks alot! I manage to did a similar one like the simple struct method, it is just the one im looking for!